# Kafka: Is it possible to create topic with specified replication factor by java client

Tags: apache-kafka

From the official document of Kafka, it said below from [4.7 Replication](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#replication)

> you can set this replication factor on a topic-by-topic basis

But from the [javadoc](http://kafka.apache.org/082/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html) of its java client, I can't find any API is relating to `createTopic` with replication factor. Is it only possible by the shell script it provided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `AdminUtils.createTopic()` method from `kafka.admin` package - https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/97e61d4ae2feaf0551e75fa8cdd041f49f42a9a5/core/src/main/scala/kafka/admin/AdminUtils.scala#L409-L418

Comment: thanks, it looks like the scala client can do it. But from the kafka doc, it said "As of the 0.8.2 release we encourage all new development to use the new Java producer.", so I am interested in if there is corresponding API of java client can do this

Comment: I'm afraid there is no pure Java API for creating topics yet but you actually may use this `AdminUtils` from Java too. The code will look a bit ugly though. But it is possible to write a Java-friendly wrapper for this for sure

Comment: thanks, is there any doc of scala client API like the javadoc? Or I should find them directly from the source code...

Comment: It looks like there is no scaladoc yet for this API so you could probably just look into Kafka sources to figure out how to use this Admin APIs

Comment: thanks, the scaladoc can be generated by `./gradlew scaladoc` command and result is at `./core/build/docs/scaladoc` from the source code

Comment: @serejja I am looking for Java doc for these class. I couldn't find. But I am using Java class for the same class from Cloudera 5.7.1